# reverse SHIFT button for numbers keys in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm tired of holding shift everytime i use numbers keys (top one, not keypad) to put symbols like ! or @ or % and others). Is it possible to reverse it, so one i hold shift and press 1 it prints 1 and when i don't hold shift and press 1 it prints ! (same with the rest of the first raw buttons: shift pressed: {`1234567890-=}, shift NOT pressed {~!@#$%^&*()_+}).
I know there are some soft for remapping buttons, but is it possible to do without remapping?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want a hardware remapping, this is the wrong site. We don't suggest hardware. What's wrong with software remapping? Why don't you like it? Maybe we can find a software solution that doesn't have the disadvantages that you experience.

Comment: Welcome to SR! As we do recommend **software** here and not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or [manuals/tutorials](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185): How much you'd be willing to pay for such software? If you're rather looking for a guide to e.g. patch the registry or the likes, your question would be off-topic here – and better fitted on one of our sister sites like, maybe, [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).